# Rails passing a list of objects to another controller with link_to_remote

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, parameters, link-to-remote

Is it possible to pass a list of `objects` to another controller in Ruby on Rails?

I have experimented with the following example:

```
class Student
 ...
end

student_list = [std1, std2, ... stdn]
```

When I use

```
<%= link_to_remote("example", :url => {:controller => 'class/assignment',
                                                      :action => 'homework',
                                                      :student => student_list})%>
```

It did not work the way I expected. `params[:student]` is equal to `"student"` (string literal).

Is there anything I did wrong, or an alternate way of doing it?

Comment: You have `sutdent` instead of `student`. It this a typo in this SO only? Also, where did you define the `student_list`?

Comment: That param is not a good student.

Comment: That was a typo when posting. The code is just fine without any error. My student_list is defined in a controller (student records are retrieved from a helper function).